# Analog of ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> from Spring for Quarkus

Tags: spring, quarkus

Are there ready-to-use analogues of ApplicationListener in Quarkus ? And what should be used for its own implementation ?

Comment: CDI has an event system (look for the `@Observes` annotation and the `Event` type). I'm not sure if there's an equivalent of `ContextRefreshedEvent` though.

Comment: See https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle

Comment: @geoand I've seen it. But I need an event that responds to a change in the application context, and not the startup or shutdown of the application

Comment: What kind of "changes in application context" do you have in mind?

Comment: As @Ladicek mentions, we'd need to know more about your use case to give a better answer

Comment: I mean when the bean is added to the context. In Quarkus, are all the beans added to the context during the build ? And the StartupEvent is what I need ?